# Parameter missing in Calculate Field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, field-calculator, census

I am trying to reclassify ACS census data into a new field for a gentrification project. I am trying to have anything above 47% classified as one and everything above classified as zero.
When I looked up an example on the esri website the field calculator window was different. For some reason I still have one parameter missing or invalid when I try to execute this. My code block states:

```
def reclass (" ")
if (" " > 47)
return 1
elif (" " < 47)
return 0
```

In the field name equation I put:

```
reclass (" ")
```

I've attached a screen shot of what my calculate field looks like.

[image]

Comment: What error message do you get when you run the code that you have presented?

Comment: I get a red "Parameter is missing or invalid" in the bottom left corner.

Comment: Your picture confirms that your indentation is astray and shows a different expression to what your formatted text does,

Comment: You did not add `:` after `def`, `if`, and `elif`. Indentation is important at `return` lines.

Comment: How do I use an indentation in code block? Thank you guys so much!

Comment: Click the space bar four times. Or better, use any text editor to write your code, then copy and paste in the code block.

Comment: It might be easier to not use python, rather open the attribute table and activate calculate field, set all target field to 0, select by attributes where your field is >= 47% then calculate the target field to 1. If there is a selection in the layer the default operation is to only affect the selected records. If you're going to work with python use a *good* text editor like Notepad++, PyWin or even Idle like @ahmadhanb says, it *really* helps when the editor keeps track of indents and changes the color of keywords, that way you know they're spelled correctly and are in the correct case.

Comment: I've had installed notepad ++. I had that on my old pc but installed it a few years ago got a new one. I vaguely remember that I needed to install arcpy and anaconda? I've been looking for directions on how to set that up again but haven't had any luck. How do I set that up again?

Comment: If ArcGIS is installed it's already in the lib folder of python. Older versions required installation of .syn files but a recent download should be fine.